# First or second difference or log for simulated real GDP data?

Tags: data-transformation, stationarity, augmented-dickey-fuller, macroeconomics, differences

For a paper I need to use simulated real GDP data to regress this on average income mobility (how much more the next generation earns).

As a hint the assignment indicates that the STATA code for a difference should be used. However, after the first difference the result is as follows:
[image: first difference real GDP]

I interpret this as a trend that is still upward sloping and not around mean zero. This is to be expected since GDP often exhibits quadratic developments over time. Therefore I decided to take the second difference, resulting in this:

[image: second difference real GDP]

This leads me to two remaining questions.

(1) After the first difference the Dickey-Fuller test indicates that there is no longer a unit root. Should I therefore stop at the first difference?

(2) Both the first and second difference contain large values, should I therefore use a log instead?